# How do I make a stage optional if there are no tagged resources in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, deployment, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a yaml structure like the below, some environments don't have some slices of the architecture so there are no resources tagged with the tag for the stage (sql in this example)I'd like to be able to make those stages optional in some way, either by turning off the error for no tagged resources, making the stage conditional by environment name or similar.

I can't seem to make it work though, it seems that maybe the resource check is happening before my condition is evaluated, or perhaps I'm using the wrong way to reference the variable?

```
parameters:
  - name: stages 
    type: object
    default:
      - stage: CI
        dependsOn: Build
        stageName: CI
      - stage: DEV
        dependsOn: DeployCI
        stageName: DEV
        ...
        ...
  - ${{ each stage in parameters.stages }}:   
    - stage: Deploy${{ stage.stageName }}
      displayName: Deploy to ${{ stage.stage }}
      variables: 
        - group: '${{ stage.stage }}'                 
        - group: 'CRIMS.Config.${{ stage.stage }}'    
      dependsOn: ${{ stage.dependsOn }}
      condition: notIn(variables['stage.stageName'], 'CI')               
      jobs:
        - deployment: DeploySQL
          workspace:
            clean: all
          displayName: Deploy SQL to ${{stage.stage}}
          environment:
            name: ${{stage.stage}}
            resourceType: virtualMachine
            tags: sql
       strategy:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a solution, I'd still be interested in any better options if there are any. I'll leave the answer unaccepted for a few days to see if there is a better solution. It seems adding the condition as an if above the deployment stage is the key

```
    - ${{ if notin(stage.stageName, 'DEV','CI') }}:
      - deployment: DeploySQL
        dependsOn: DeployAll
        workspace:
          clean: all
```

Answer (score 1):

Glad to know you have resolved it with `if expression`.

In your original `condition` expression `condition: notIn(variables['stage.stageName'], 'CI')` , the problem here is `stage.stageName` is not a variable actually.

To fix it, you can define a new variable with value `${{stage.stageName}}`, and use the new variable in condition instead.

Yaml as below:

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

parameters:
  - name: stages 
    type: object
    default:
      - stage: CI
        dependsOn: Build
        stageName: CI
      - stage: DEV
        dependsOn: DeployCI
        stageName: DEV


stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
      - job: job1
        steps:
          - checkout: none
          - script: echo Stage Build

  - ${{ each stage in parameters.stages }}:   
    - stage: Deploy${{ stage.stageName }}
      displayName: Deploy to ${{ stage.stage }}
      dependsOn: ${{ stage.dependsOn }}
      variables:
        stagenamevar: ${{ stage.stageName }}             # define new variable here
      condition: notIn(variables['stagenamevar'], 'CI')    # use new variable in condition           
      jobs:
        - deployment: DeploySQL
          workspace:
            clean: all
          displayName: Deploy SQL to ${{stage.stage}}
          environment:
            name: ${{stage.stage}}
          strategy:
            runOnce:
              deploy:
                steps:
                - script: |
                    echo use environment
                    echo $(stage.stageName)    # output the value for confirmation
                    echo $(stagenamevar)

        - job: job1
          steps:
            - script: echo job1
```

[image]